# Microsoft Office Developer tools for VS 2012 - Preview 2, problem with templates

Tags: visual-studio-2012

After in installed the Microsoft Office Developer tools for VS 2012 and opened one of my SP 2010 projects, the ContentType wizard no longer shows up. Also the icon for the ContentTypes in the solution Explorer is replaced with a big red X

[image: Error]

I tried repairing VS2012 and Microsoft Office Developer tools without success.

I'm running Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved after a re-install of VS 2012